# How to mutate a dataset using an arithmetical expression in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to dynamically mutate a data set using an arithmetical expression in R.
I tried following without success.Appreciate some help.

```
newCol <- 'newCol=gear+wt'

mutate(mtcars,!!newCol) ## This inserted a column newCol=gear+wt

mutate(mtcars,!!sym(newCol)) ## THis gives an error
```

> 'Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Binding not found: newCol=gear+wt.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem of non-standard evaluation of dplyr.

Quote your expression first, and then unquote.

```
newCol <- quo(gear + wt)

dplyr::mutate(mtcars, !! newCol)
```

This one is very helpful here: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html

Worth reading, it's great :)

Comment: to put my question in perspective, i am not able to accept the expression as a input and perform the calcuation in shinyR.

Comment: library(shiny)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)
library(data.table)

ui <- pageWithSidebar(
        headerPanel = headerPanel('data'),
        sidebarPanel = sidebarPanel(#         fileInput(
                #         'mtcars', h4('Uplaodmtcardata in csv format')
                # ),
                uiOutput('formula')),
        mainPanel(dataTableOutput("data"))
)

Comment: server <- function(input, output, session) {
        mtcarsFile <- reactive({
                input$mtcars
        })
        
        
        xxmtcars <-
                reactive({
                        as.data.table(mtcars)
                })
        
        
        
        output$formula <- renderUI({
                textInput('formula',
                          h5('formula'))
                
        })
        formulaPars <- reactive({
                !!(input$formula)
        })

Comment: newCol  = reactive({
                quo(formulaPars())
        })
        
        output$data <- renderDataTable({
                as.data.table(mutate(xxmtcars(), cyl + (!!newCol())))
                
                
        })
   
}

runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))

Comment: I think this might be worth a new question - as your orginal question has (hopefully) been answered sufficiently with my answer

Comment: If you agree, accept this as an answer (checkmark next to the answer). And post a new question , referring to this question here. And do no forget use the [tag:shiny] tag

Comment: ShinyR code is upload.I dont know how to share the code when i write a comment. Hence code has been split and sent.Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @user10270838 see my comments above

Comment: @user10270838 you should not post to much code inside a comment anyways. For code snippets use backticks: `

Answer (score 0):

You don't use <- when entering a function argument. in `dplyr`, mutate is a function that lets you create new columns based on any calculation. Here's an example:

```
library(dplyr)
dataset <- mtcars
dataset %>% mutate(newCol = gear+wt)
```

No need for `sym` here.
Hope that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)

newCol <- eval(parse(text='gear+wt'),list2env(mtcars))

mutate(mtcars, newCol = newCol)
```

Or, use base R instead of mutate:

```
mtcars$newCol <- eval(parse(text='gear+wt'),list2env(mtcars))
mtcars
```